# Retrieve "Local" Named Range From sheet (not workbook) Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a excel file (XLSX) I want to read with Apache POI with many sheets. I want to filter these sheets to read only the ones where a named range is defined let's say "section1" on the sheet.

For instance lets say there  5 sheets in the workbook and 3 of them have defined a local named range "section1" only these are relevant. I did not find how to that in Apache Poi we can only retrieve all names from the workbook.

What I want is iterate throught each relevant sheet and read the section for each one.

Comment: Have you tried to look for [`Name`s](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Name.html) in the workbook / sheets?

Comment: I ended up doing that using getNames on the workbook and passing a sheet number to retrieve the name associated to the sheet thanks for you answer

Comment: I actually only left a comment. If you got a solution, you can answer your question yourself. Best would be a brief description and some code examples. That would add value for future readers and may even provide some reputation for you.